# How to print a PDF file in a same page using PDF.js

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, pdf.js

I am facing the problem to print a pdf file(Ex: www.example.com/test.pdf ) on the same page rather than in a new tab. As of now, I am using **Iframe** tag to load and print a pdf file in the same page.

Unfortunately, I am getting a **cross-domain** object error in Firefox browser since my site URL(www.example.com) and PDF URL(www.example.com/param1/param2) belongs to the same domain. I could not find a solution to this issue.

So, I am looking to PDF.js plugin to achieve this. But in all the examples they are printing it in a new tab. Are there any other solutions to print a pdf file on the same page?

Comment: I really dont believe `www.example.com` and `www.example.com/param1/param2` causes a cross domain error.

Comment: Unfortunately it's causing an error in my case